# strange conditional

Tags: conditionals

What's the difference between 1 and 2? 
Is 1 a good conditional?

1. I can't imagine the consequences if the police found out.
2. I couldn't imagine the consequences if the police found out.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are very tricky conditionals, because *consequences* is itself a proposition which 'hides' a  middle term.  I've put it in boldface:

1. I can't imagine the consequences if the police found out.

   In the hypothetical case of the police finding out, **there would be consequences**; right now, in the real present, I am unable to predict those consequences.  *OR*

   (*This could also be understood as* In the as yet undetermined case that the police *did* find out, there { were / will be } consequences; right now, in the real present, I am unable to say what those consequences {were / are / will be}.)
2. I couldn't imagine the consequences if the police found out.

   In the hypothetical case of the police finding out, **there would be consequences**; at that time, in the hypothetical future, I would be unable to predict those consequences.

In both of these the middle term contains the modally remote (*would*) term which satisifes the requirement that the protasis (*IF*-clause) and apodosis (*THEN*-clause) must have the same modality. They are quite different from ordinary conditionals, with no middle term:

3. <sup>ok</sup>I will go to jail if the police find out. *and*
4. <sup>ok</sup>I would go to jail if the police found out. *but not*
5. <sup>∗</sup> I will go to jail if the police found out. —***unless***, as John Lawler points out, the context calls for found *to be understood as a simple past whose factuality is unknown to the speaker, in which case it has indicative modality.*

None of 1-4 is necessarily counterfactual; they will all support adding *—and they will* or *—but they won't* at the end. 5, if it bears the indicated construction cannot be understood as a counterfactual.

Comment: _I'll go to jail if the police found out; if they didn't, I'm a free man. We'll have to see whether they did or not._

Comment: @JohnLawler Lhude sing goddam. Yes, *found* could be an ordinary preterite. Fixed.

Comment: If the police find out, I'll go to jail. If the police have found out, I'll go to jail.  If the police found out, and I'm not yet in jail, I'm not going to jail.

Comment: @TimRomano Your 3d (supposing it to be true) doesn't establish my #5 as a counterfactual: it establishes it as a false factual.

Comment: @StoneyB:  What I meant to imply is that there's no way to build a "conditional bridge" between the simple past and the present.  If the police had found out,  I would have gone to jail. If the police have found out, I'm going to jail.

Comment: @TimRomano Sure there is: *If John caught the plane at 3 o'clock then he's over Baltimore now.* The only constraint on actualization conditionals is that the event in the protasis precede that in the apodosis. Even that constraint disappears with inferential conditionals, where a past event may be inferred from a future condition: "If John lands at 7 o'clock tonight he left at 3 o'clock this afternoon."

Comment: @StoneyB:  A modal strikes my ear as natural there: *If he caught the plane at 3PM, then he should be over Baltimore now.*   People do use the simple present there, but it sounds odd to me. It's as though they're saying "If" when they mean "Since".

Comment: @TimRomano It's contextual, I think. "Where's John?" .. "Well, if he caught the 3 o'clock he's in the middle of a lightning storm over Baltimore. Hope he's OK."

Comment: @StoneyB: I wonder if the simple past in such contexts is not an inferential conditional but backshifting, to signal a greater degree of doubt about the fact in the protasis? Compare "If he *took* the non-stop flight out of Atlanta, he's already in Boston."  vs. "If *he's taken* the non-stop flight out of Atlanta, he's already in Boston." Does the latter form with the present perfect express relatively less doubt about which flight he has taken?

Comment: @TimRomano M m m . . . I don't *think* so. In this case the past event entails the present state, and vice versa, so they are equivalent for purposes of inference. I think the choice between them will be governed by discourse context and idiolect and a certain degree of linguistic Brownian movement rather than by any semantic difference. But in the end that may be just *my* idiolect.

Answer (score 3):

They're both right but they mean different things.

In your first sentence, you currently, while speaking, cannot imagine the consequences. "Can't" is thus the normal indicative mood.

In the second sentence, you're talking about a potential inability to understand in a hypothetical situation in which the police find out, and "couldn't" is conditional.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Is the if-clause part of 1 counterfactual? Does it refer to an unlikely current situation or a possilbe past situation?

Comment: I don't think it's a counterfactual conditional. But please be aware that some people will say you should use the present tense for "find out". In my experience of British English as spoken by real people, the present and past are used interchangeably in this context.

Answer (score 1):

"I can't imagine the consequences if the police found out." - May be overlooked in the informal conversations or acceptable as speakers who aren't particularly conscious of their language or style speak this way.

On the other hand, "I can't imagine ... if the police *find* out." is correct and it's more like saying the same 'as a matter of fact' as if it's going to happen and it's only a matter of time.

The second follows the rules for such *conditional* sentences and puts forward a real hypothesis / assumption.

Comment: More here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/conditional-subjunctive-and-conditional-indicative

Comment: I don't think 1 is an exmaple of sloppy speech. I took it from an English grammar publised by the reputable publisher Longman.

Comment: I guess, Longman Grammar documents both spoken and written language grammar and usage. I'd be curious to know what it says about the above sentence.